# Brightness buttons on Macbook Pro 7.1

Tags: nvidia, brightness, macbook

I'm following the steps [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Trusty).
The website says to set the driver to

> NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

and `nvidia-current` (not `nvidia-current-updates`), but I don't see that option. I set the driver to

> NVIDIA binary driver version 331.38 from nvidia 331 (proprietary, tested)

then rebooted the computer and now it says I am using the recommended drivers.

Nonetheless, I can't re-enable the brightness buttons when following the website instructions. First I tried running `nvidia-xconfig` in a terminal and it says,

```
billy@billy-MacBookPro:~$ nvidia-xconfig
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.
ERROR: Unable to write to directory '/etc/X11'.
```

then I tried `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and it says,

```
(gedit:4739): Gtk-WARNING **:
 Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
 The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

And the `xorg.conf` text document opens but is blank (nothing to edit/change).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the nvidia-settings application. There will be a tab called 'X server display configuration' which allows you to "save to X configuration file".

Once this is done you can access the file with sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

There will be a section called `Section "Monitor"`. Under that add the following lines:

```
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Apple"
Option         "DPMS"
Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

Reboot, and you should have working brightness controls on your macbook.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I ended up following original instructions from that ubuntu link, even though my xorg.conf was blank and did not have a monitor settings, I just copied and pasted.




Now my major issue is the fan always runs at high speeds,draining the battery, and laptop becomes abnormally hot when streaming video.  Even though I installed TLP http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/tlp-05-released-install-it-in-ubuntu.html, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have macfanctld installed?

Comment: no I don't should I install that with TLP?

Comment: Yes it can be installed alongside TLP. Please install macfanctld before your macbook overheats.

Comment: OK I'll definately do that.  I just tried to boot back into Ubuntu with rEF

Comment: OK I'll definately do that.  I just tried to boot back into Ubuntu with rEFInd, but it says "No bootable device--insert boot disk and press any key." I'm using the latest version of rEFInd 0.8.3 and I checked OS X (10.9.4) disk utility and I still have all the extra partitions for Ubuntu. Any more ideas :)

Comment: Where did you install grub? The bootloader needs to be installed on dev/sda? (Your ubuntu partition) in order for refind to detect it.

Comment: at startup refind shows ubuntu at "Boot Linux from FAT volume."  After looking online I still don't know how to change it to dev/sda.

Answer (score 1):

Editing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the following configuration worked for MackbookPro7,1 (with NVIDIA 340.108 proprietary drivers installed):

```
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Apple"
Option         "DPMS"
Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

Note: If `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is not available, you'll need to create one - by exporting from the `nvidia-xserver` application.